# Python apache beam ImportError: No module named *** on dataflow worker

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Summary: Some local packages works and some doesn't

My beam application's structure:

```
-setup.py

-app/__init__.py
-app/main.py

-package1/__init__.py
-package1/one.py

-package2/__init__.py
-package2/two.py

-package3/__init__.py
-package3/three.py
```

In main.py:

```
from package1 import one
from package2 import two
from package3 import three
```

In setup.py

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='beam',
    version='1.0',
    install_requires=['apache-beam[gcp]',
                      'google-cloud==0.34.0',
                      'google-cloud-bigquery==0.25.0',
                      'requests==2.19.1',
                      'google-cloud-storage==1.12.0'
                      ],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

When running, by using `python -m app.main` :

With direct runner (locally run), no problem.

With DataflowRunner (send to gogole dataflow),
I have this error:

> apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 642, in do_work
>       work_executor.execute()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 156, in execute
>       op.start()
>     File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 344, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
>       def start(self):
>     File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 345, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
>       with self.scoped_start_state:
>     File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 350, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
>       pickler.loads(self.spec.serialized_fn))
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 244, in loads
>       return dill.loads(s)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 316, in loads
>       return load(file, ignore)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 304, in load
>       obj = pik.load()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
>       dispatchkey
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
>       klass = self.find_class(module, name)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 465, in find_class
>       return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
>       **import**(module)
>   ImportError: No module named three

This is "a bit" frustrating because I double/triple/... check what can be the difference between those packages, and they are the same. Sane `__init__.py` file (empty, no weird or hidden characters in them). Same type of structure in `*.py`. But for some reason, the package 3 just doesn't want to cooperate.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share the full command line used to run with DataflowRunner? Some things to try: use the --setup_file flag, rerun "python setup.py sdist", --save_main_session

Answer (score 5):

It's been almost a year, but I had a very similar issue and was able to resolve it, so posting for others stumbling onto this page.

In my case, there is nothing special about `package3.three`, it just happens to be the first one that the worker tries to import. In fact, removing `package3.three` (e.g. by temporarily including its contents directly in `main.py`) leads to the same error with one of the other modules.

While I don't fully understand the root cause, running with a file invocation `python app/main.py` rather than the module invocation `python -m app.main` resolved the issue. I'm guessing there is some conflict between the packaging in `setup.py` and the implicit packaging in module invocation.